# How to add listeners to javafx UI component with scala

Tags: swing, scala, javafx-2, javafx, observer-pattern

I'm using Scala and `Publisher` trait to listen the change on my data component and publish/update display to swing UI component (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260387/how-to-add-listeners-to-swing-components-in-scala))

I recently rewrite my program to use `Javafx2` and `Scala`, and i cannot use the recent binding project `Scalafx`, because only some of part of my program switch to javafx (which is embedded into swing JFrame).

What is the best syntax i can use in scala to have the same (or similar) behaviour based on scala.swing `Publisher` trait ?

Do you have some link or simple example to illustrate this method ?

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest at the moment is reusing the patterns from `scala.swing` that implemented the *Publish/React* system.
An example can be taken from the [scala.swing.Component](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/swing/scala/swing/Component.scala) in the old `scala.swing`  repository.

The idea is to create the possibly most generic wrapper for all *javafx* classes that need to publish events, and implicitly convert these classes to this wrapper.

The wrapper would define the logic for bridging events from *javafx* listeners to the *publish/react* system.

An example code would look like this, and is based on the aforementioned `scala.swing` code

```
  package scala.fx.react

  object ScalaFxReactive {
      /*
       * Can't say if Node is the best and only class that should be converted.
       * You should make implicit publishers from any fx class that supports the
       * addEventHandler(someEventType)
       */
      implicit def toPublisher(peer: Node): ScalaFxComponentPublisher = new ScalaFxComponentPublisher(peer)

  class ScalaFxComponentPublisher(peer: Component) {

    /**
     * Contains publishers for various mouse events. They are separated for
     * efficiency reasons.
     */
    object mouse {
       /**
        * Publishes clicks, presses and releases.
        */
        val clicks: Publisher = new LazyPublisher {

          lazy val clicked = new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
            def handle(e: MouseEvent) {
               /*
                *This is the most critical part: you need
                * to check if it's possible to create the swing 
                * event from an fx event, eventually through an
                * implicit conversion
                */
               publish(new MouseClicked(e))
            }
          }

          def onFirstSubscribe() = peer.setOnMouseClicked(clicked)
          def onLastUnsubscribe() = peer.setOnMouseClicked(null)
          /*
           * probably better:
           * def onLastUnsubscribe() = peer.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)
           */
        }
        /**
         * Publishes enters, exits, moves, and drags.
         */
        val moves: Publisher = new LazyPublisher {
           lazy val entered = new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
             def handle(e: MouseEvent) {
               publish(new MouseEntered(e))
             }
           }
           lazy val exited = new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
             def handle(e: MouseEvent) {
               publish(new MouseExited(e))
             }
           }

           /*
            * Need implementation
            */
           lazy val moved = new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
             ...
           }
           def onFirstSubscribe() {
             peer.setOnMouseEntered(entered)
             peer.setOnMouseExited(exited)
             ...
           }
           def onLastUnsubscribe() {
             peer.setOnMouseEntered(null)
             peer.setOnMouseExited(null)
             ...
           }
         }
       }
     }
```

Then you can support reacting in your components as you do with `scala.swing`

```
class MyComponent {
    import scala.fx.react.ScalaFxReactive._

    listenTo(node)

    reactions += {
      ...   
    }

}
```

The code is to be taken as a rough sketch and will not compile as it is. It points in a possible direction, but the complete solution could be an interesting enough library for people that, like you, need to progressively bridge legacy `scala.swing` application to the `javafx` library.